# How do I conditionally use threads in a perl script?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a perl script that I've developed that runs on hosts that have different versions of perl, sometimes compiled with threads and sometimes without.

I have a

```
use if $Config{"useithreads"}, "threads";
```

And all of my thread-specific code is in similar conditionals.

However, during the compile phase, perl still chokes on threads::all, threads::running, etc.

How can I unsure my script runs on both threaded and non-threaded perls?

```
 [ worr on worr-mn1 ] ( manage_usr_local_admin ) % perl -c acct_mgr_ng.pl
Bareword "threads::joinable" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at acct_mgr_ng.pl line 117.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at acct_mgr_ng.pl line 541.
```

Comment: You want to _require_ threads in a BEGIN block if $Config{useithreads}, not _use_ it.

Comment: show what "chokes on" looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When threads is loaded, perl knows that `threads::all` (and friends) is a subroutine call, even without parentheses or `&`; since threads may not be loaded, just explicitly call it with parentheses: `threads::all()`

Answer (score 2):

`use` statements are parsed at compile-time. You want to use `require` or [Module::Load](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Load.html) to pull in modules conditionally at run-time.

Something like this should work:

```
use Module::Load ();
if($Config{'useithreads'}) {
    Module::Load::load("threads");
}
```

Comment: I took @ysth's suggestion and did a use if, however compile on non-threaded machines still fails when it's looking for the threads::all, threads::running, etc. symbols.

Comment: fails *how*?  show us what happens!  show us the code that uses threads::all, etc

Comment: I updated my question to reflect @ysth's changes and to show the compilation output

Comment: @worr, we need to _see the code_ that produces your error, not just the error output.  Better:  we need to be able to _run_ demonstrative code that produces your error.